# Measurement on a web site

Tags: css, measurement

Should you mix `em` with `px`?

As `em` is based on font size and `px` is based on the screen.

So the question boils does to - how to generate an image when most of the web site is using `em` ?

Comment: what image? didn't understood your question..and you can mix `em` with `px`, your choice, but better use `em's`

Comment: You use images for buttons, background etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fonts are designed to be used in an array of sizes; thus font engines have no problem scaling them up/down with precision; however, images have always used a rigid measurement (regardless of unit). Consequently, resizing them tends to F them up -- sometimes a litte, sometimes a lot. This is especially true when the browser is doing the resizing. Browsers weren't designed as photo-editing tools.

If you're building image-based menus, and you're also allowing the menu to scale upward in size, maybe a redesign is in order. If not a redesign, than perhaps an elimination of one factor (no scaling, or no images).

Answer (score 3):

Normally, images have intrinsic dimensions in pixels. But you can scale them according to font size, if they are e.g. buttons that should match text in size. Just create a large enough image (scaling down works much better than scaling up) and set e.g. the height of the image to `1.5em`. When you set height only and not width (or vice versa), browsers scale the image so that the width : height ratio is preserved.

However, buttons are better created using CSS, not images. Background images can be scaled using advanced CSS features (`background-size`), which however have limited browser support.

Comment: Do note that larger images increase the file size which causes longer download times and more bandwidth needed. Also, CSS sprites are a must-have, especially when talking about buttons. (And CSS3 is very good at creating buttons. Rounded corners, gradients, shadows...)

Comment: I wanted to put a bounty of 100, and the message that I would like to tell me how to mix the units of measurement. But hey it is Monday and things are going down hill. Suicide on Wednesday!

Answer (score 3):

1em is equal to the current font size. 2em means 2 times the size of the current font. E.g., if an element is displayed with a font of 12 pt, then '2em' is 24 pt. The 'em' is a very useful unit in CSS, since it can adapt automatically to the font that the reader uses

The 'em' unit is equal to the computed value of the 'font-size' property of the element on which it is used. The exception is when 'em' occurs in the value of the 'font-size' property itself, in which case it refers to the font size of the parent element. It may be used for vertical or horizontal measurement

pixels (a dot on the computer screen),px can be resized in IE as well. em is a relativ size to the inherited size by it's parent element and actually has the same meaning as %.

Comment: The thing is that you can specify the font sizes - see the options menu for full details. If I was incline as I am at the moment (i am having difficult seeing today) would it be nice to ramp up the font size and enable the images to grow according

Comment: diffrence between em and px description

Answer (score 2):

you can mix, but it's not recommended. I would create a container element and use px on that element if the parent is using em.

Comment: It would be the benefit for people of hard of seeing. Having the font as large (to understand) but the image for them on the screen would be reasonable to read and understand.

Comment: are you sure you don't want to just use media queries to scale up an image?

Answer (score 2):

I personally mix both. You can do it either way without errors.
It depends on preference, and practices. There are others too:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Answer (score 2):

I find it always best to use px in the html,body and em for all the rest in regards to font. However, take a look at relative units(vw vh v-min v-max): http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

Answer (score 1):

Use css3

```
background-size: auto 100%;
```

on the container of the content.  The background will resize relative to container height and the container height will increase relative to font-size, no matter how it is set.